# Subtracting number of days from todays date using value in another field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, datetime

I have an integer field named `"Priority"` with values ranging from 5 to 30 days. I want to use the `now()` function to subtract the integer to give a new date. The formula I tried is below but it just returns a null value.

```
now() - to_interval("Priority")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is slightly more complicated than the expression you used in your question. If you are trying to populate a field with a date type, or a date & time type, then you need to use the [`to_date()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-date-and-time-to-date) function combined with [`now()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#now) to get the output of subtraction in date format.

Because your original field type of `"Priority"` is an integer, you need to convert the values inside that field to string first before using [`to_interval()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-date-and-time-to-interval). Also, `to_interval()` takes string type like `5 days`, `2 hours`, or `5 days 2 hours` (please read the help associated with the function), so you need to add in the expression `|| ' days'` to concatenate the values in the `"Priority"` field with `days`.

Assuming the field type that you want to populate is a date type, as in the following example (the name Date field has a date type), here is the final expression:

```
to_date(now()) - to_interval(to_string("Priority") || ' days')
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, but a caution to future readers: note the blank space within ' days'.  The expression will fail if the blank is not included, as I found out to my frustration!